# A technicality in the Radon-Nikodym theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, radon-nikodym

The Radon-Nikodym Theorem says:

If a measureable space $(S,\,\Sigma)$ admits $\sigma$-finite measures $\mu$ and $\nu \ll \mu $, there is a unique (up to sets of $\mu$-measure zero) $\Sigma$-measurable function $ f:S\rightarrow \left[\right.0,\,\infty \left.\right)$, such that, for any measurable set $ A\in \Sigma$,
$$
 \nu (A)\,=\,\int_{A}\,f\,d\mu\,\;.
 $$
Named the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$, the function $f$ is commonly written as $d\nu/d\mu$.

Question.

A function $\,S\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\,$ is called Lebesgue-measurable iff the preimage of any open set from $\mathbb R$ is measurable in $(S,\,\Sigma)$.

Would it be right to say that the Radon-Nikodym derivative $f$ is Lebesgue-measurable?

Comment: I might be missing a detail. What is the difference between $\Sigma$-measurable (which is given by the theorem) and Lebesgue measurable (as you define it in this question, which might not be standard)? Note that open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are Lebesgue-measurable.

Comment: The term "Lebesgue measurable" is used when the domain $(S,\Sigma)$ is the real line $\Bbb{R}$ (or more generally $\Bbb{R}^n$) equipped with the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{L}$. This has a very specific meaning. So, in general it's not right to say $f$ is Lebesgue-measurable. The term $\Sigma$-measurable is the more general terminology, and accounts for all the cases, in particular "Lebesgue-measurable" or "Borel-measurable" etc.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for your comment. It answers my question. I now see that my definition of a Lebesgue-measurable function was too broad. The correct definition implies that the domain of such a function is $R^n$, not an arbitrary set S.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Interestingly, on Wiki the term "Lebesgue-measurable" is applied to two different situations. In one case, it is $f:\,S\longrightarrow\mathbb R$. In another case, it is $f:{\mathbb{R}}\longrightarrow S$. I am wondering if this is an oversight or a somewhat frivolous extension of terminology.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function#Notable_classes_of_measurable_functions

Comment: I'm not sure I see exactly which parts of the wikipedia page you're referring to (perhaps if you take a screenshot I could make a comment). In any case, to be perfectly clear, one should always specify the $\sigma$-algebra on both the domain and target space, so that measurability then refers to these two $\sigma$-algebras. This is sometimes a hassle because it makes sentences more wordy, but I am of the opinion that clarity >>>> conciseness.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I mean this paragraph from Wiki: "A Lebesgue measurable function is a measurable function $ f: ({\mathbb{R}},\,{\cal L})⟶({\mathbb{C}},\,{\cal B}_{\mathbb C})$, where $\cal L$ is the σ-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets, and ${\cal B}_{\mathbb C}$ is the Borel algebra on the complex numbers $\mathbb C$. Lebesgue measurable functions are of interest in mathematical analysis because they can be integrated. In the case $f : X→\mathbb R$, $\,f$ is Lebesgue measurable iff ..."

Comment: right ok they shouldn't have added in the extra adjective "Lebesgue" in the second part of the sentence (because like in my first comment the term Lebesgue measurable is only used when the domain is Rn equipped with the Lebesgue sigma algebra). Also, keep in mind that Wikipedia is peer edited, and while it is very good for a lot of things, there are bound to be mistakes (some small ones like this, and some bigger ones). Usually Wikipedia is good for an overall idea and a reasonable amount of detail, but just don't trust your life with it :)

Comment: @peek-a-boo OK, got it. Thank you. Will be vigilant :)